# Keystore file error during release in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

When outputting in Flutter, I encounter a Keystore file error. If I entered the file address correctly.

[image]

Comment: please add your key.properties

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to:

- Place your `.jks` file inside `android/app/`.
- In `android` directory place your `key.properties` file.
- In `android/app/build.gradle` file paste it inside `android {}`

```
 signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
```

and this outside any brackets:

```
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set the key inside the users folder inside the current user then try again
keystore file not fount for sigining config 'release'

1. Open Android Studio
2. Drag and drop your keystore file over the app folder
3. Change the path of file like following

> ```
> storePassword=my_password 
> keyPassword=my_password 
> keyAlias=key    
> storeFile=key.jks
> ```

Click in File -> Sync project

Comment: > Multiple task action failures occurred:
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
      > com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key key from store "C:\Users\mansour\StudioProjects\android\app\upload-key.jks":
 No key with alias 'key' found in keystore C:\Users\mansour\StudioProjects\android\app\upload-key.jks

Comment: if you move the keystore to app folder no need for the full path only set storeFile=upload-key.jks @Mansourafshar